# money-rails parse currency symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency-formatting, money-format

I'm using the money-rails gem to parse currencies, however it's not parsing the currency symbol as otherwise specified in the documentation (http://rubydoc.info/gems/money/frames).

I get this, when trying to parse:

```
1.9.3p484 :011 > "£20.00".to_money
 => #<Money fractional:2000 currency:USD>
```

It doesn't recognize the "£"-symbol as GBP.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It does exactly what it says it does here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/money/String:to_money the number is shown assuming with 2 decimals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it supposed to recognize the symbol? Maybe you're not setting

```
Money.assume_from_symbol = true
```

From the docs examples:

```
# Assumptive Currencies
Money.assume_from_symbol = true
Money.parse("$100") == Money.new(10000, "USD")
Money.parse("€100") == Money.new(10000, "EUR")
Money.parse("£100") == Money.new(10000, "GBP")
```

(Maybe it works with `String.to_money` too)

Comment: I was completely blind to that line! Thanks @rlecaro2 !